# Poll: "arguments for/against" vs "advantages/disadvantages"

Tags: discussion

Following up this question:

[How to word “advantage/disadvantage” or “arguments for/against” questions?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/88/97)

... and the suggestion in the [Private Beta Extension](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/93/97) discussion that it (among others) should receive a little more attention, here is a poll:

**Should one, both or neither of the following forms of words be encouraged or discouraged on politics.stackexchange.com?**

- "What are the advantages and disadvantages of X?"
- "What are the main arguments in favour of and against X?"

Comment: You are trying to ban words... it is not the words that are the problem but context of them

Comment: This is... Really not a great way to resolve this issue. I'd say start a discussion, but there are already several - please just participate in them. It's more important that we flush out reasoned arguments now than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

We should **encourage** "What are the main arguments in favour of and against X?" and **discourage** "What are the advantages and disadvantages of X?".

Comment: I am supporting this one over the others. The reason: In and out of themselves "adv/disadv" questions are not a problem in SE format (leaving aside the usual "this is a list question" complaints). But as usual, in politics **even the definition of what poses an advantage and disadvantage would be subjective, both in terms of "does X ACTUALLY offer Y as advantage", and "is Y an advantage in the first place?"**.

Comment: On Christianity.SE, I find myself almost always wanting to understand Why someone believes X.  By asking "Why does X support Z," I learn about perspectives other than my own.  This phrasing comes pretty close to that.

Answer (score -2):

We should **discourage** *both* "What are the advantages and disadvantages of X?" *and* "What are the main arguments in favour of and against X?".

Answer (score -2):

We should neither encourage nor discourage either; both are fine.

Answer (score -5):

We should **encourage** "What are the advantages and disadvantages of X?" and **discourage** "What are the main arguments in favour of and against X?".